# Fetch Email Id and name of the user who commented in my facebook group or page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-apps, facebook-group

I have a Facebook app which has Facebook login as a product. My requirement is to fetch the comments on my posts in group/page and view the email and name of the user who has commented.

I'm using graph API to fetch the comment from a post with

> {post-id}/comments

Further more I can fetch the user from each comment by

> {comment-id}?fields=from

although this works when a user has given permission to my app. I'm unable to get the email of the user from the above endpoint.

Also how can I mandate that the users in my Group/Page must give permissions to my app if I'm a group admin/page admin.

Comment: you cannot "force" users, you can just "ask" them. what is the use case for getting the user details?

Comment: @luschn I need to user details to create his account on my app. primarily user email and name. so as to "Ask" them how would I do it is the question.

Comment: yes, but how would the user benefit from this? anyway, you would need to present a link where they could login.

Comment: @luschn basically the use case is I have a e-learning platform and I want to go live with some exclusive contents and provide few coupons on the live show which would be availed on a first come first served basis. I want the users to comment on the live video when they are interested in the coupon. For the people who have commented on my post I want to create a guest account with email and name. so that they can avail the coupon on my site. This is my use case but could not get the email by the above method. In some cases I did not even get the name if the user is not registered with my app.

Comment: would it help if I add my app in the group settings?. I just want users to get a dialog saying accept app to enter the group or something. just curious if there is a way to do this.